# Allocating and reallocating a struct and its elements

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a few questions about allocating memory to structs and their members.

Suppose I have a struct like this:

```
struct _MyStruct
{
    char *a;
}
typdef struct _MyStruct MyStruct;
```

1. I want 'a' to be a dynamic string and I want to allocate memory to it. Should I allocate memory to MyStruct too in this case? Example:

   ```
   MyStruct *myStr = malloc(sizeof(MyStruct)); //necessary?
   MyStruct *myStrCopy = myStr;
   myStrCopy->a=malloc(sizeof(char));
   //checking for null//
   ```
2. Now suppose I allocated an X amount of memory to the struct (`myStr`). Now, when I allocate memory to 'a', is the memory allocated within the memory allocated to myStr, or does it get a new block of memory?
3. Can I allocate more memory to 'a' than I allocated to myStr?
4. Suppose I want to enlarge 'a' with `realloc()`. Should I enlarge `myStr` first? If  I do, then by what amount of memory `(sizeof(myStr)*size_of_my_string)`?

Comment: [Oh, if it's a possessive...](http://www.homestarrunner.com/sbemail89.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. I want 'a' to be a dynamic string and I want to allocate memory to it. Should I allocate memory to MyStruct too in this case?

Well, your MyStruct always needs to exist, but there are several ways to do this and you should go for the simplest one that fits your use case.

Basic approach:

```
MyStruct myStr;
myStr.a = malloc(N); // "N chars please!"

// You can still get a pointer to this object:
foo(&myStr);

// Don't forget to free the `char` buffer later
free(myStr.a);
```

Dynamic allocation — valid, but not inherently necessary:

```
MyStruct* myStr = malloc(sizeof(MyStruct));
myStr->a = malloc(N); // "N chars please!"

// It's already a pointer, so:
foo(myStr);

// Don't forget to free the `char` buffer later
free(myStr->a);

// And then the struct
free(myStr);
```

> 2. Now suppose I allocated an X amount of memory to the struct (myStr). Now, when I allocate memory to 'a', is the memory allocated within the memory allocated to myStr, or does it get a new block of memory?

It's a new block.

Each block of dynamically allocated memory is entirely separate. When you made the member variable `a` a pointer, you ensured that although `a` lives within the struct, the thing it points to does not (unless you make it point to itself, lol).

```
myStr (or *myStr):                       your malloc'd memory:

0          32                       0   8   16   24   32   40  ...
+----------+                        +------------------------------+
| char* a——|———————————————————————→| text or whatever here        |
+----------+                        +------------------------------+
 (somewhere in memory)                 (somewhere else in memory)
```

The above diagram is valid no matter which way you constructed `myStr`.

> 3. Can I allocate more memory to 'a' than I allocated to myStr?

Yeah, whatever you want. It's separate. You have *indirection*.

> 4. Suppose I want to enlarge 'a' with realloc(). Should I enlarge myStr first? If I do, then by what amount of memory (sizeof(myStr)*size_of_my_string)?

No.

Answer (score 2):

Just for clarification:
`myStr` and
`a` are just pointer to some memory location. This does not mean they are sharing the same memory location.

So allocating either `myStr` or `a` is not growing the variable it self.
It requests new memory somewhere in the virtual memory space of the process and stores the address in the corresponding pointer..

So to answer you question: Yes you can allocate a memory for `a` which is larger than `myStr`.

Update for better illustration:

```
 0x000 | 0x004 | 0x008 | 0x0012 | 0x0016
   ^                                 ^
   |                                 |
   myStr                             a
```

So `myStr` could be located in memory somewhere completly different compared to `a`.

Answer (score 1):

Not needed to allocate for structure.Just for char* is enough. Say

```
MyStruct str;

str.a = malloc( sizeof(char)*10);
```

str will be in stack. Memory pointed by 'a' will be in heap. So when str goes out of scope, the object will be destructed. But not the dynamically allocated one which is pointed by 'a'. We have delete it manually.
The size of structure will be same won't vary with the size of dynamic memory pointed by 'a'.

Just reallocate the memory pointed by 'a'.

```
str.a = realloc(a, sizeof(char)*20);
```

Comment: Misuse of "stack" and "heap" and terrible formatting but the only otherwise correct answer so +1

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh just said `Without the allocation to myStr first, trying to dereference myStr (to reach a) is undefined behaviour`. Doesn't it mean that what you wrote should **not** be done?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit is it?? Can you please show the use of `myStr` in above code? Please stop making irrelevant and misleading comments just because you disagree with the OP.

Comment: Yes. We have to manually destruct the dynamic memory. Memory for struct will be there already as soon as you do MyStruct str;.

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh I think that LightnessRacesinOrbit got my point better. The code I posted was supposed to clarify the question. It does not mean that I want to write in the exact same way I wrote there.

Comment: @user2979612 I understand, and he is very right from his point of view. The mismatch happens, when we mix up the variable types. in my case, `myStr` is a pointer and the memory allocation is must. In this answer `str` is not a pointer and memory allocation is not a concern of coder. Both are correct. It's a matter of efficiency and choice.

Comment: Even after, if anything is **wrong** in my answer, I am all ears.

Comment: But I'm actually pretty confused here. As a beginner programmer I don't even know which advice I should follow.

Comment: You should follow the advice by @LightnessRacesinOrbit. Really there is no need for the pointer and dynamic allocation there. I was trying to go along the lines of example code. :-)

Comment: @Raams Which language is this `str.a = new malloc( sizeof(char)*10);`, please? :-)

Comment: @Raams That said, you can get rid of `sizeof(char)` as a multiplier. It's guaranteed to be `1` in `C`.

Answer (score 0):

1. First case

   ```
   MyStruct *myStr = malloc(sizeof(MyStruct)); //necessary?
   ```

   yes, very much. Without the allocation to `myStr` first, trying to dereference `myStr`  (to reach `a`) is  [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).. Also, FWIW,

   ```
   myStrCopy->a=malloc(sizeof(char));
   ```

   allocates only memory for only one `char`, be sure that is what you actually want. If you really want that, in that case, you can rewrite that as

   ```
   myStrCopy->a=malloc(1);
   ```

   as `sizeof(char)` is guranteed to be `1` in `C`.
2. Every allocation through `malloc()` and family gives you a new memory, if successful.
3. You can, and you should. There is no relation actually. They are separate variables and need seperate memory allocation.
4. No, only `realloc()` on `a` should suffice.

Comment: Now why is allocating memory to myStr necessary? What do I do with this memory if I don't need to enlarge it or touch it (except free())? And yes, allocating 1 char is what I actually want.

Comment: @user2979612 I think I covered that, din't I? `Without the allocation to myStr first, trying to dereference myStr (to reach a) is undefined behaviour.`

Comment: @user2979612 Ah,, I see, no issues. :)

Comment: It's not "necessary" at all. Give it automatic storage duration. Why on earth would you dynamically allocate the `MyStruct` in this case? Total nonsense.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes you're very right, but given that OP has used  a pointer, my point stands valid. it **is** necessary.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: One could argue that the use of a pointer is part of the question. "Is it necessary to use dynamic allocation? [and therefore a pointer too]". Besides, using a pointer doesn't _require_ dynamic allocation. `MyStruct s; MyStruct* ptr = &s;`

Comment: Then not making it a pointer in the first place is an option. Could save me from writing some unnecessary lines of code. In order to pass it to other functions by reference I do need to make it a pointer though (yes?).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit If that is your concern for nitpicking, I never mentioned **dynamic**, I only mentioned _allocation_. Without an allocation, using the pointer to dereference is UB.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit sir, also not the question by OP says `Should I allocate memory`..... there is nothing **required** about dynamic, either. In any form, an allocation is necessary.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Don't you start. ckruczek thinks I'm being "pedantic", and now according to you I'm "nitpicking". Guys, learn to accept criticism: your advice here is _wrong_. And don't call me "sir", thanks.

Comment: @user2979612: No, not necessarily. You can pass a pointer to the object no matter how it was allocated. `MyStruct s; foo(&s);` Try to avoid dynamic allocation unless you need it, which you usually don't.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I still did not get my answer, in either case. I am entitled to ask for clarification, right? Otherwise, the criticism is waste, if I don't understand the point you're making, right?

Comment: I get your point @LightnessRacesinOrbit of argueing if it is really necessary to use pointers here(and believe me, I am on your side it is not). BUT you also have to accept that the OP asked this question with pointers, so the answer is applicable.

Comment: I cannot be held responsible for y'all misunderstanding the question.

Comment: I would really appreciate that you might also provide a answer :)